# How to create charts upon user input with chart.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I need advice to how to create a module in MVC 5 that creates charts the way user wants. I mean user says what he or she wants and system produce it for them. I guess I have to use jQuery and ChartJS ok and in the back end I think I should use TSQL to produce the data chart needs but how do you query data base upon user input. For example user says I want column A of table B where A is greater that x OK. So how can I:

1. Show fields of table in the UI the rest I can do
   then I execute the query and pass the data back and show result
   so it comes to this
2. How the frog I show specific table field names and when user select that field. Code understand it and query on that field

PS: I can code C# jQuery Razor for front end and I am using MVC5 and .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: the best way would be take use inputs to the server and build sql query. So, you need to display available fields on the page using dropdown or checkboxes, user selects the fields they want, get selected fields on server, build custom sql and return data.

Comment: That is exactly What I did and right thank you @Pirate